# How to turn list into dataframe without losing text format in Python?

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe, beautifulsoup

I webscraped this webpage.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import pandas as pd

url = "https://www.ecb.europa.eu/press/pressconf/2022/html/index_include.en.html"
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content)

data = []

u = soup.select('div.title > a'):
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(f"https://www.ecb.europa.eu{u[0]['href']}").content)
    data.append({ soup.select('main .section p:not([class])')})

print(data)

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# results (it may not be the same text
[... <p><strong>Duisenberg:</strong> My answer is, well, in the first place when something is before the courts you do not comment. I don't comment and particularly not when it concerns such an esteemed colleague of mine. So, on the hypothetical question whether other people would be eligible for the job, I think it is wise not to go into that either. </p>]
```

The problem is that when I turn `data` into a dataframe, it remains in a list format which is difficult to handle. I would like it to be saved as a unique object without losing its properties (`</p>`,`</strong>`).

If I do this, it loses the division in pararaphs and bolds that will be needed for manipulation.

```
data = []

u = soup.select('div.title > a'):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(f"https://www.ecb.europa.eu{u[0]['href']}").content)
    data.append({
        'text':' '.join([p.text for p in soup.select('main .section p:not([class])')])
    })

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# with this however I lose the breakdown in paragraphs, bold characters etc. I'd like to keep them in the text.
```

Can anyone help me with this?

Thanks!

Comment: Is the issue that df has your data but it is in a nested list? That is because `.select()` returns a list.  You probably wanted `data = soup.select('main .section p:not([class])')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note sure if I understand it correctly, but if you like to convert the resultset to text you can do it like that:

```
''.join([str(e) for e in soup.select('main .section p:not([class])')])
```

#### Example

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import pandas as pd

url = "https://www.ecb.europa.eu/press/pressconf/2022/html/index_include.en.html"
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content)

data = []

u = soup.select('div.title > a')
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(f"https://www.ecb.europa.eu{u[0]['href']}").content)
data.append({'text':''.join([str(e) for e in soup.select('main .section p:not([class])')])})

pd.DataFrame(data)
```

#### Output

```
text
<p>Good afternoon, the Vice-President and I welcome you to our press conference. </p><p id="_Hlk93669934">The euro area economy is continuing to r...
```